# Replace Ubuntu 16.04 by Windows (7 or 8.1)

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, usb, windows-8

I am using Ubuntu Mate 16.04, now I want to change to Windows 7 or 8.1.

I tried some tools as WinUSB. Like this [tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

But it just show Grub Bootloader with Windows Loader Recovery.
Tab to Windows option, but it can not install, some message showed like that "this device is not bootable" ( sorry I did not remember detail)

Any help!!

Comment: http://harish2704.blogspot.com.es/2015/04/creating-bootable-windows-usb-from-linux.html

Answer (score 1):

General answer (is true for installing any OS):

You need an installation media (dvd, usb, recovery partition) and boot from it. You boot from it by editing your BIOS and setting it to do so or by selecting the device that has the media (also from BIOS). How you do that  depends on the BIOS and how you want to install. You might also need a(n) (U)EFI partiton (also created from BIOS).

If you have the installation media in your system and it still boots to the currently OS installed the system does not know you want to boot from some other media.